# Rounding amount up to 2 decimals based on the 3rd number after decimal

Tags: c#, rounding

I Have to get amounts as below

```
1099948.275 = 1099948.27,
1099948.276 = 1099948.28,
1099948.274 = 1099948.27
```

when I use `Math.Round(1_099_948.275, 2)` I am getting output as 1099948.28 but not 1099948.27. I even tried with `awayfromzero` and `toeven` and none of them are working. Any idea?

Is there way to find 3rd number after decimal and if it is 5 just take first two number after decimal else go with mat.round?

Comment: I want to round it to 2 decimal. if I have 3 decimals then i have to round it to 2decimal. If i have 1099948.275 value i want output as 1099948.27 and if i have 1099948.276 value i want out put as 1099948.28 and if i have 1099948.274 value i want output as 1099948.27.

Comment: Subtract 0.001 then round. Whether or not that works for negative numbers I do not know because you did not specify how these should be rounded

Answer (score 0):

This is not how rounding works, neither in C# nor in Math.

By default, anything 5 or more is rounded up, and anything less than 5 is rounded down. This is called "Away from Zero" rounding.

> **Rounding away from zero**
>
> Midpoint values are rounded to the next number away from zero. For example, 3.75 rounds to 3.8, 3.85 rounds to 3.9, -3.75 rounds to -3.8, and -3.85 rounds to -3.9. This form of rounding is represented by the MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero enumeration member.

The other mode is rounding to the closest even number. This is *half* of what you're looking for. In this way, when something ends with a "5" (the midpoint), that number is rounded to the closest even number, which could be up or down. This is done to distribute out the chances a rounding affects one particular party in a monetary transaction.

> **Rounding to nearest even, or banker's rounding**
>
> Midpoint values are rounded to the nearest even number. For example, both 3.75 and 3.85 round to 3.8, and both -3.75 and -3.85 round to -3.8. This form of rounding is represented by the MidpointRounding.ToEven enumeration member.

The source for both of the above quotes are on [the Math.Round documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-5.0#midpoint-values-and-rounding-conventions).

There is no supported rounding system that *always* rounds a 5 down. You'd need to inspect the value first to see if the last digit is a 5, then truncate the digit rather than attempt rounding.

Comment: .NET 5 has [rounding options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-5.0) for rounding towards zero and towards negative infinity, but neither of those seem to work in [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CHBZqG).

Comment: You know, I was starting to feel confident for once...

Comment: Scratch that, `TowardsZero` rounds any fractional amount to zero, not just the midpoint. So  it seems to be equivalent to flooring. So I think you are right, there is no option to round X.5 to X for all values of X.

Answer (score 0):

One could implement your own rounding strategy:

```
public static double RoundDown(double value, int precision)
{ 
    var rounded = Math.Ceiling(value * Math.Pow(10,precision) - 0.5) / Math.Pow(10,precision);
    return rounded;
}

public static decimal RoundDown(decimal value, int precision)
{ 
    decimal scale = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<precision;i++)
    {
        scale *= 10;
    }
    var rounded = Math.Ceiling(value * scale - 0.5M) / scale;
    return rounded;
}
```

Usage:

```
var values = new double[] {1099948.275, 1099948.276, 1099948.274 };
Console.WriteLine("double:");
foreach(var value in values)
{
    var rounded = RoundDown(value, 2);
    Console.WriteLine($"{value} = {rounded}");
}

Console.WriteLine("decimal:");
var values_m = new decimal[] {1099948.275M, 1099948.276M, 1099948.274M };
foreach(var value in values_m)
{
    var rounded = RoundDown(value, 2);
    Console.WriteLine($"{value} = {rounded}");
}
double:
1099948.275 = 1099948.27
1099948.276 = 1099948.28
1099948.274 = 1099948.27
decimal:
1099948.275 = 1099948.27
1099948.276 = 1099948.28
1099948.274 = 1099948.27
```

Comment: How to do this if it is decimal value?

Comment: change `double` to `decimal`. Or better yet, add an overload with a different input type.

Comment: @Tronics I just realized that it's not a simple as changing the type (and found a bug). Updated the answer for both types.

Answer (score -1):

You can get what you need by subtracting 0.001 from the number before rounding it

Math.Round(1099948.275-0.001,2)

Edit:

to answer some of the comments

Math.Round(1099948.270-0.001,2) will still give the correct answer which is 1099948.27
similarly for any other number.
negative numbers may need to be handled differently depending on requirements.

Comment: `1,099,948.270` ?

Comment: `1,099,948.2751`?